# I am unable to raise exceptions correctly in my flask app

Tags: python, exception, flask

In my flask app, I am unable to throw an error due to the following line of code.

Note that MyException is a class that is subclass of the Exception class, and it imports status from the flask_api.

```
raise MyException(
            status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST, "File does not exist: " + file_path
        )
```

However, this yields the following error in my terminal when I get to this error in my webpage:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a tuple.
```

Am I unable to raise exceptions in flask?

Answer (score 0):

You can usually do this with the [`abort`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.abort) function:

```py
from flask.wrappers import Response

@app.route("/someroute")
def someroute():
    try:
        raise MyException("some message")
    except MyException as e:
        abort(400)
        abort(Response(e))
```

If you raise a custom exception directly, you need to add a handler for that exception or you'll get a generic 500 error.